# Difference between int a; int b; and int a, b. ( Respect to Memory Management)

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

I know that both `int a; int b;` and `int a, b;` are doing the same. But I want to know is `int a, b;` using less memory during compilation than `int a; int b;` . I mean is there any difference between them ?

Comment: Why would there be a difference?

Comment: no it is exactly the same

Comment: shmosel, I even do not know, maybe compilator is constructed that it is easyer to read data in a one row rather than in two. I do not know, that's why I asked.

Comment: Do you really mean during *compilation*, or during runtime? Who cares about memory during compilation?

Comment: It is intersting both, but abowe I mean speed of compilation process.

Comment: Short answer: No. long answer: Nooooooooooooo. :-)

Comment: Well, there could be a tiny difference in memory consumption when parsing this fragment, but that would depend on the specific compiler and version. It’s unpredictable, which source code form would require less memory. Further, the way memory management works, you wouldn’t notice the difference anyway, as all the magic happens within pre-allocated memory chunks of a much bigger size…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference in the slightest.  None whatsoever.

Answer (score 5):

**FYI**

There is ***no difference in terms of Performance or output or anything else***.

You can do both. But I would prefer declaring **`int a,b;`** because why should I write an additional line for that simple thing.

For  ***readability and maintenance*** issue you can use **`int a; int b;`**

Comment: I thought that variable will take that 2 bytes only after initialization, I mean only when I write int a=5; but not when int a; .

So spaces and tabs are cousing what ? ( garbage collector executes, compilator speed problem, ... )

Comment: IntelliJ Amiya, I do not, but I asked that just because I do not know the answer and it is interesting for me.

Comment: Java coding conventions call for each variable to be declared separately. It's better for readability and maintenance.

Comment: Why do you say `int` is 2 bytes? And how is that relevant to anything?

Comment: @LewBloch Yes .

Comment: *why should I write an additional line for that simple thing* -- because you respect those who will have to maintain your code and try to make their job easier by following accepted convention.

Answer (score 4):

Except your source file is a bit bigger (how much depends on encoding) and compilation takes a part of a part of a part of a second longer, there's no difference. Really, it's so tiny and ignorable.